# No space left on device (Ubuntu 16.04.5)

Tags: ubuntu, python, memory, python3

I'm really having difficulties understanding and finding out what is eating the space on my Ubuntu instance on Dreamcompute. 
I've installed **Odoo 11**  (ERP platform running on python). It works ok for a couple of hours and than it suddenly gives :

> my_instance_ip didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

As far as I've come to understand there are some log files that grow very large very fast. But I can't find which of them because when i try to display their sizes, they are to small. But when I delete their contents the page gets back up running for a couple of minutes and fails again and this time no more logs are generated.

I've tried everything. Been reading for this issue for three days now and still can't find a fix.

To avoid some downed leads :

- I have a lot of space on my drive : 80 Gb, so adding more space makes
  no sense.
- I've deleted the instance, installed every thing brand new    and it
  happened all over again.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Can you run `df -i` and see if any of the `IUse%` columns read 100% (or near 100%)?

Comment: Nothing that you have provided indicates that you are running low on space. Have you checked the output of `df -h` when the issue occurs?

Comment: @AndyDalton this are the stats generated by the command you suggested                 `Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           503482    400 503082    1% /dev
tmpfs          505810    503 505307    1% /run
/dev/vda1      384000 126791 257209   34% /
tmpfs          505810      1 505809    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          505810      3 505807    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          505810     16 505794    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          505810      4 505806    1% /run/user/1000z` . though here in the comments you can't see clearly but no, none is taking 100%.

Comment: @NasirRiley something that led me to believe that this might be related to space running low is this error : ` cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device` when i try to autocomplete a file name or when i try to install a new package.

Comment: @MaroParo Edit your question and add the output of `df -i` and the error that you are getting. In the future, remember that it's important to include information like that so that you can get the help that you need more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
du -Sx / | sort -n
```

This will show you the directories that need the most space. Add other mount points as needed.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily answer the question and is only suggesting the same as the previous comments. It needs to first be established as to whether or not space is the issue before any answers are given.

Comment: @NasirRiley Actually the suggestion is no the same as the comments. The comments suggest `df`, which is also a good idea. The question "what is eating the space" is answered by `du`, not `df`. But `df` should show the file systems, one of the partitions might be full.

Comment: Your answer is the same. We don't know whether or not space is the issue. `df` will show that just as `du` will. Before giving an answer, it's best to let him provide the output of the commands so that we are sure of whether space is the issue because there's no way to be certain of that with what he's given. It is for that reason that what you've provided doesn't answer the question. Your answer would be better as a comment so that it can be determined if space is even the issue.

Comment: @RalfFriedl none but the same a above , none of the files show more than 2 Gb of space.